# beautiful soup 4 issue in mulitple data fetching. it is confusing me

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, bs4dash

When i am fetching one data it is working fine as i mentioned below code. **Whenever i am finding all datas in a similar tagging (example - {'class': 'doctor-name'}) it showing output as none.**

Single tag output

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """
<a class="doctor-name" itemprop="name" href="/doctors/gastroenterologists/dr-isaac-raijman-md-1689679557">Dr. Isaac Raijman, MD</a>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('a ', {'class': 'doctor-name'}).text)
print(soup.find('a ', {'itemprop': 'name'}).text)
```

> Output -
> [Dr. Isaac Raijman, MD,
> Dr. Isaac Raijman, MD]

Finding all using similar tagging but showing output as none-

```
import requests, bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://soandso.org/doctors/gastroenterologists"
page = requests.get(url)
page
page.status_code
page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup
print(soup.prettify())
lists = soup.find_all('section', attrs={'class': 'search-page find-a-doctor'})
for list in lists:
   doctor = list.find('a', attrs={'class': 'doctor-name'})#.text
   info = [doctor]
print(info)
```

> Output - none

Please help me to solve this issue. Share your understanding as a code and #hastags definitions also fine.

Comment: Please add sample data that is returned from that link

Comment: Note: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it will overwrite the Python `list()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is built up by the browser and is not returned in the HTML. An easier approach is to request it from the JSON API as follows:

```
import requests

headers = {'Authorization' : 'eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJleHAiOjIxMjcwNDQ1MTcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZGV2ZWxvcGVyLmhlYWx0aHBvc3QuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kZXZlbG9wZXIuaGVhbHRocG9zdC5jb20ifQ.zNvR3WpI17CCMC7rIrHQCrnJg_6qGM21BvTP_ed_Hj8'}    
json_post = {"query":"","start":0,"rows":10,"selectedFilters":{"availability":[],"clinicalInterest":[],"distance":[20],"gender":["Both"],"hasOnlineScheduling":False,"insurance":[],"isMHMG":False,"language":[],"locationType":[],"lonlat":[-95.36,29.76],"onlineScheduling":["Any"],"specialty":["Gastroenterology"]}}
req = requests.post("https://api.memorialhermann.org/api/doctorsearch", json=json_post, headers=headers)
data = req.json()

for doctor in data['docs']:
    print(f"{doctor['Name']:30}  {doctor['PrimarySpecialty']:20}  {doctor['PrimaryFacility']}")
```

Giving you:

```
Dr. Isaac Raijman, MD           Gastroenterology      Memorial Hermann Texas Medical Center
Dr. Gabriel Lee, MD             Gastroenterology      Memorial Hermann Southeast Hospital
Dr. Dang Nguyen, MD             Gastroenterology      Memorial Hermann Texas Medical Center
Dr. Harshinie Amaratunge, MD    Gastroenterology      Memorial Hermann Texas Medical Center
Dr. Tanima Jana, MD             Gastroenterology      Memorial Hermann Texas Medical Center
Dr. Tugrul Purnak, MD           Gastroenterology      Memorial Hermann Texas Medical Center
Dr. Dimpal Bhakta, MD           Gastroenterology      Memorial Hermann Texas Medical Center
Dr. Dharmendra Verma, MD        Gastroenterology      Memorial Hermann Texas Medical Center
Dr. Jennifer Shroff, MD         Gastroenterology      Memorial Hermann Texas Medical Center
Dr. Brooks Cash, MD             Gastroenterology      Memorial Hermann Texas Medical Center
```